# DatabaseMetaData.getColumns returns columns of similar named tables

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, hibernate, database-metadata

In my database I have tables "EMPLOYEE_DETAILS" and "EMPLOYEE DETAILS" with different columns for both tables. When I used the getColumns() method of the DatabaseMetaData (java.sql.DatabaseMetaData) to get the column details of the table "EMPLOYEE_DETAILS", I am getting the columns of both "EMPLOYEE_DETAILS" and "EMPLOYEE DETAILS".

I have tried this for databases Oracle, MySql and MSSQL. The result is same.

The code which I have used to call the getColumns method is given below :

```
String tableName = "EMPLOYEE_DETAILS";
ResultSet columnResultSet = databaseMetaData.getColumns(null, null,tableName, null);

while (columnResultSet.next()) {
System.out.println(columnResultSet.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
System.out.println(columnType = columnResultSet.getString("TYPE_NAME"));
System.out.println(columnSize = columnResultSet.getInt("COLUMN_SIZE"));
}
```

Could anyone please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Take a look at getSearchStringEscape()  .  "_" is probably a wildcard character in the table search.

Comment: @OldProgrammer that is exactly the answer, as you probably knew.  I'm curious: why do people post answers as comments instead of answers?

Comment: It was just a hunch.